# C# SQL Query for Hiding Multiple String And Showing The First Line With The Same Identifier

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to create a report using datagrid in C# where it will show the multiple data but will hide the identifier if they have the same value in the table.

The results should be something like this
[image]

Here's my code and query in fetching the data in the database.

```
//Seperated public class
public DataTable ViewDailyRecord(BELReport belreport) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ReportStorageDetails WHERE Date=@Date";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",belreport.DailyReport);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(dr);

        return table;
}

// Code inside my form
belreport.DailyReport = Convert.ToDateTime(date_day_Daily.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

DataTable table = balreport.ViewDailyRecord(belreport);

dgv_daily.DataSource = table;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? Exception? Different result??

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the data in SQL or C#?

Comment: No. There's no problem with that. What I'm trying to do is like that excel format above. You know, if you select all the data in the table using the native select * from, it only show all of the query. What I want is, if the identifier has multiple copy, then it will hide the identifier(except the first one) but the value of with the same idenfier will remain visible.

Comment: @Stringfellow I don't know if there's a query about that. Or else there's a properties in C# that the datagrid will do that for me. :(

Comment: If I were to solve it in C#, I'd sort by the first column and then iterate over the set of rows. While iterating, I would keep track of values I've encountered and then set subsequent, same named values to empty string.

Comment: @Stringfellow what if there's a multiple different identifier? You know,

Comment: Normally, this is done on the client side (in C#), but if you have SQL Server 2012+, it is easy to do on the server side as well using `LAG` function.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Do you have a sample query? :) That would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having SQL Server Management Studio 2014 doesn't mean that the version of SQL Server is the same, but anyway..

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use `LAG` function to get the value of the "previous" row. The definition of "previous" depends on the order of rows, so you need to be able to sort them in a meaningful way.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ColumnA = LAG(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA, ColumnB)
    THEN '' ELSE ColumnA END AS FinalColumnA
    ,ColumnB
    ,CASE WHEN ColumnC = LAG(ColumnC) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA, ColumnB)
    THEN '' ELSE ColumnC END AS FinalColumnC
    ,ColumnD
FROM ReportStorageDetails
WHERE Date=@Date
ORDER BY ColumnA, ColumnB;
```

---

Normally, this kind of post processing is done on the client side (using C#), because end user usually is able to re-order rows as he likes.

Comment: how can I use it my class query :/

Comment: Just put this query in your code instead of your `SELECT`. What's the problem with that? Obviously, type the names of your columns instead of `ColumnABC...`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm currently testing it now. :)

Comment: And what if I want to hide not just the identifier, but also the ColumnC if there's the same value. Where should I add it?

Comment: @mark, I updated the answer. Just use the same method as with `ColumnA`. Use `LAG` to get the value from the previous row and check if it is the same or not.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir, It will help me a lot to move forward on my new task :) God bless +